# RegEx multiple lines

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have this text:

```
text1 without brackets
text2 (with brackets)
```

and I need two groups in every line:

```
group#1: text1 without brackets
group#2: 
group#1: text2
group#2: with brackets
```

Here is a link for this example: [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/4k4mp)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(.*?)(?:\s*\(([^()]*)\))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f2J5bQ/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(.*%3F)(%3F%3A%5Cs*%5C((%5B%5E()%5D*)%5C))%3F%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars as ew as possible
- `(?:\s*\(([^()]*)\))?` - an optional sequence of patterns that is tried at least once:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `([^()]*)` - Group 2: 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `$` - end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try pattern: `([^(\n]+)(?:\n|\(([^)]+))`

Explanation:

`([^(\n]+)` - first capturing group: match one or more characters other than `(` or `\n` so it will match everything until opening bracket or newline character

`(?:...)` - used in order to make use of alternation and not create second capturing group

`\n|\(([^)]+)` - match newline or bracker `(` and one or more characters other than closing bracket `)` storing it into second capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WL9IER/1)